# How to run separate instance of the app engine application for every user?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, task-queue

I have an application that does a long running job and pushes the task in the task queue. Currently, when different users login to the application and start the upload job, the job merges with the existing task and expected output is not achieved.

What I need exactly is to run different instances of app engine application for every user as every user will be needing much amount of computing power and these instances must be dynamically get created when every new user is encountered.

I had referred different docs on instance classes and scaling types, but didn't get to know how to start a new instance for every different user.

Please also suggest if there is a better solution to this.

Comment: Can you post the code for your uploads?

Comment: Yes, I will formulate it well and post as it is quite lengthy, but let me explain it, the upload module fetches the Google Spreadsheet from the user given url and the upload process starts with lots of computation on data, I needed that each user having different urls shall login from their google accounts and separate tasks for them should run for them in task queue and according to me separate instances for each user should get allocated with new memory and resources

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not used this myself, [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref#scaling_elements) suggests this could do it for you:

> **<max-concurrent-requests>**
>
> Optional. The number of concurrent requests an automatic scaling instance can accept before the scheduler spawns a new instance

Try setting that value to `1` in your `appengine-web.XML`
 (see the documentation link above for more info).

Comment: Thanks, I went through the documentation, but I found that this option is avaliable for <automatic-scaling>, in my application I am using <basic-scaling>, please can you help me out with the similar configuration for <basic-scaling>?